# Azure search not returning documents that contain query

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to have azure search return documents that contain a search query like `Veri` for example. Right now it only returns documents that only have `Veri` in them, I want it to return documents that have `Veriz`, `Verizo`, and `Verizon` etc.

My URL looks like so
`const url = config.DEFAULT_AZURE_SEARCH_URL + '/indexes/temp/docs?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview&searchMode=all&queryType=simple&search=' + terms + '&$skip=' + skip + '&$top=' + limit`

and terms = `Veri*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language analyzer are you using to analyze the text?

Generally, Lucene analyzers perform stemming of the tokens. This may change the token before it is stored in the index.
eg:'Eating', 'Eat', 'Eaten' can all be stemmed and stored as 'eat' in the Lucene index.

Can you try to switch to Microsoft English analyzer 'en.microsoft', and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I'm currently using the REST API and node, so unsure how to change to the English analyzer. Cannot see in documentation. Thanks

Comment: Fixed, I had the original term wrapped in " " so it was trying to find an exact match on Veri*. Removing that fixed the problem, thank you.

Comment: That's great. Now that you have figured it out, can you post an answer to this question. This will help others who run into similar issues. Thanks!